# How can I redirect to the certain page when I clicked on my side-nav menu

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I create a menu table and menu seeder inside my database. However when I tried to click on the company menu on my website it saying that *$menu is undefined* but when I tried to change to *jobs.index*(this the one which is working fine) for my route it works but it will goes to the job.blade.php not company.blade.php I do not know which part is wrong inside my code.

**companycontroller.php**

```
class CompanyController extends Controller
{
 public function index()
{

$data = Company::latest()->paginate(5);
return view('company.index', compact('data'))
->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
 }

 public function insert_logo(Request $request)
{
$request->validate([
'company_logo'  => 'required|image|max:2048',
'company_name' => 'required'
 ]);

$image_file = $request->company_logo;

$image = Company::make($image_file);

Response::make($image->encode('jpeg'));

$form_data = array(
'company_logo' => $image,
'company_name'  => $request->company_name,
 );

Company::create($form_data);

return redirect()->back();
}

public function fetch_logo($image_id)
{
$image = Company::findOrFail($image_id);

$image_file = Company::make($image->company_logo);

$response = Response::make($image_file->encode('jpeg'));

$response->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');

return $response;
```

}

Comment: How do you pass `$menu` to `job.blade.php` or any of the other views that work? If you need data in "multiple" views you could use [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers) (or [Sharing Data With All Views](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views))

Comment: I am using the Route::resources then I just put job.index as the route

Comment: You do have something like a `JobController` with an `index` method that returns the view?

Comment: i think i know where is my fault

Comment: Right, that's where you get `$menu` and pass it to the view. Do the same in your `CompanyController`